# Mutex gone wrong?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I am trying Pthreads and its pretty basic program: I have two shared variables (declared global) among all threads

```
long Sum = 0;
long Sum1 = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutexLock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

In thread function:

```
for(int i=start; i<end; i++) //start and end are being passed to thread and they are being passed correctly
{
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexLock);
 Sum1+=i;
 Sum+=Sum1;
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexLock);
}
```

main() in case one needs for reference:

```
int main()

{

pthread_t threadID[10];

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
 int a = (i*500) + 1;
 int b =(i + 1)*500;

 ThreadStruct* obj = new ThreadStruct(a,b);
 pthread_create(&threadID[i],NULL,ThreadFunc,obj);
}

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  pthread_join(threadID[i], NULL);
}

cout<<"Sum: "<<Sum<<endl;
cout<<"Sum1: "<<Sum1<<endl;

return 0;

}
```

**OUTPUT**

***Sum: 40220835000
Sum1: 12502500***

Run again

***Sum: 38720835000
Sum1: 12502500***

Run again

***Sum: 39720835000
Sum1: 12502500***

**PROBLEM**

***Why I am getting a different value for `Sum` in each iteration?***
Rest whole code is working ok and output of Sum1 is correct - no matter how much times do I run the code. (Only issue is in Sum). Am I doing something wrong in use of mutex here?

**UPDATE**

*If I use local variables as **@molbdnilo** specified in his well detailed answer, this problem is solved. In start, I thought that mutex is irrelevant here but I tested it a number of times and observed the cases when not using a mutex results in recurrence of this problem. So, solution of this problem (courtesy: Answer by **@molbdnilo**) is to use local variables WITH mutex and I have tested it to work perfectly!*

Comment: You haven't described the problem.  What is the value of `Sum` that you're getting?  What do you expect?  How many threads are you using?  What are the values of `start` and `end`?

Comment: Semantically it seems correct. Just an idea to think about... perhaps you need to increase the critical section so, that the foor loop (and perhaps something more) is also within it?

Comment: @dmi Dear I done that too! I even tried to use two locks - one for first assignment and another for second. Every try giving same answer

Comment: @MichaelBurr Can you please check the updated question? I hope it explains the problem now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a threading problem – the problem is that even though the order of additions to `Sum1` doesn't matter, the order of additions to `Sum` does.

Consider the much shorter sum 1 + 2 + 3 and the following interleavings

1:

```
Sum1 = 1 + 2 = 3
Sum = 0 + 3 = 3
Sum1 = 3 + 3 = 6
Sum = 3 + 6 = 9
```

2:

```
Sum1 = 1 + 3 = 4
Sum =  0 + 4 = 4
Sum1 = 4 + 2 = 6
Sum = 4 + 6 = 10
```

3:

```
Sum1 = 2 + 3 = 5
Sum =  0 + 5 = 5
Sum1 = 5 + 1 = 6
Sum = 5 + 6 = 11
```

You could solve this by having the threads compute their own sum-of-sums independently and adding them afterwards.

(Notice that there's no concurrent mutation here, so locking anything can't make any difference.)

For a more concrete example, let's limit your program to two threads and the sum from 1 to 6.
You then have one thread computing `1 + 2 + 3` and one doing `4 + 5 + 6`.

At a glance, thread one should also compute `1 + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3)` and thread 2, `4 + (4 + 5) + (4 + 5 + 6)`.
Except they don't – every time they use it, `Sum` may have been modified by the other thread.

So thread one may compute `1 + ((1 + 4) + 2) + ((1 + 4) + 2 + 3)`, or something else.

When you use local variables, you keep each thread's result independent of the others.

(I think this problem is a pretty good illustration of how shared mutable state can complicate things in unexpected ways, by the way.)

Comment: I tried something like this: `a = Sum1;` (`a` is local variable) and `Sum+=a;` and its solved now! I just wonder one thing now: How come does shared variable disturb the value while local doesn't (while I used mutex in both the cases)?

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes I agree this problem really helped me understand an important concept in mutex and really thanks for explaining it in depth.